# What's the best practice for executor and connector usage?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

When using tomcat 8.5.4, if understand correctly, connector and executor component can use its own created threadpool through the following configuration.

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix ="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4" />
```

and if connector component wants to share the threadpool coming from executor, the configuration should be like this.

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort=t"8443" acceptCount="1000" />
```

i'm not sure which one is better while handling large amount of concurrent requests from client. Any ideas?

Comment: Where's the following configuration ?

Comment: Sorry about that, something’s wrong, I submit it on the iphone, anyway, now it’s working.

Answer (score 0):

The [Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/executor.html) can help when you have several *Connectors* and you want to give common limits to the whole system in just one configuration. If you have one single Connector, it won't change anything ; if you have 10 Connectors with different loads, you would not use the Executor if you want to give different priorities and keep a minimal availability for the associated applications.

You didn't say how many concurrent requests are a *large amount*. If you have enough CPU, you will set *maxThreads* accordingly.

Comment: There is one change; configuring an `<Executor>` allows threads to be de-provisioned while a lazy configuration (`<Connector>` only) will never remove threads from the pool. It usually doesn't make much of a difference, but there is in fact a difference in behavior.